# Array in PHP does not work

Tags: php

I am trying to add array data from mysql. But only the last row details are getting added. I tried array_push also but did not work. Can any one help

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM server_details";
$result=mysqli_query($dbC,  $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$services=array( 
    $row['server_name'] => array($row['server_add'] => $row['port'])
); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not creating a new array in every iteration of the loop :

```
$sql      = "SELECT * FROM server_details";
$result   = mysqli_query($dbC,  $sql);
$services = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $services[$row['server_name']] = array($row['server_add'] => $row['port']); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for this:

```
$services[ $row['server_name'] ] = array($row['server_add'] => $row['port']);
```

In the end you'll get in your `$services` variable an associative array, indexed by `server_name` column values.

If they're not unique, you should do this instead...

```
$services[ $row['server_name'] ][] = array($row['server_add'] => $row['port']);
```

This way you'll still get the same associative array, but its values will be indexed arrays; thus you won't lose any information for records with the same `server_name`.